# Cournot Oligopoly in Bayesian Game Theory

Tags: game-theory

I have this Cournot game in which $n$ firms produce quantities $q_1, \ldots, q_n$ with respective marginal costs $c_1, \ldots, c_n$.  They all sell at price $P=1-(q_1 + \cdots + q_n)$.  For any $i$ the marginal cost $c_i$ has equal chance being $0$ or $c$ where $0<c<\frac{4}{n+3}$, and each firm $i$ knows $c_i$ only.  I need to find a symmetric best response.

My attempt so far is to express the profit of firm $i$ as $(P-c_i)q_i$, take the derivative, set to $0$.  This results in $1-(q_1+\cdots+2q_i+\cdots+q_n)-c_i=0$.  I could then make a matrix equation and possibly try to solve it, but this seems like I have too many unknown quantities.  Something doesn't quite feel right.

Since the solution is supposed to be symmetric I'm wondering if I instead should have reasoned that for all $i,j$ we have $q_i=q_j$ and therefore profit is $(1-nq_i - c_i)q_i$ and again maximize that.  If I do, I get $q_i=\frac{1-c_i}{2n}$.  I'm not sure if that's the answer or if I should do more ... at no point do I seem to have used the probabilities with which firms believe other firms to have their marginal cost.

Any insight would be appreciated.